# the necessary of the "rosparam set use_sim_time true " in gmapping

Tags: navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,

I would like to know the necessary of  "rosparam set use_sim_time true " when I build exact map by using gmapping and rviz.

When I used "rosparam set use_sim_time true " before "rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping scan:=base_scan", my map becomes error " No map received" in rviz. If I don't use "rosparam set use_sim_time true " ,The error don't appear.

If I don't use ""rosparam set use_sim_time true " , Can I build exact map?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244215/the-necessary--of-the-%22rosparam-set-use_sim_time-true-%22-in-gmapping/) by [sasadasd](https://answers.ros.org/users/27743/sasadasd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 104 on 2016-09-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is not necessary if you are not using `rosbag` to play back sensor data.

My setup is:

- a real robot P3DX
- a laser
- a cellphone running Android APP to teleop robot

I didn't set the param 'use_sim_time'. I just ran gmapping and teleop robot to build the map, and then used `map_saver` to get the map and .yaml file.

---

Originally posted by [Shay](https://answers.ros.org/users/27777/shay/) with karma: 763 on 2016-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sasadasd](https://answers.ros.org/users/27743/sasadasd/) on 2016-09-22**:
Thank you for your helpful infomation!